# How to reference HtmlTemplate variables in javascript in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to reference a variable I've set in my html template inside the javascript section of my HTML file.

Using the Google example code

```
function doGet() {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  t.data = SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
      .getActiveSheet()
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
  return t.evaluate();
}
```

I could reference t.data in my HTML with

```
<? data ?>
```

But how do I reference the same variable in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
<script>
  const data = <? data ?>
</script>
```